# Why proc with generic types specified explicitly is not working?

Tags: nim-lang

If types for `map` specified explicitly the example won't compile, why?

This works

```
import sequtils

let nlist = @[1, 2]
let slist: seq[string] = nlist.map(proc (v: auto): auto = $v)
```

But this won't:

```
let slist: seq[string] = nlist.map[int, string](proc (v: auto): auto = $v)
```

Comment: the error you get (`Error: type mismatch ...
expression: map(nlist)` I guess is due to the fact that UFCS is not able to see the op parameter once you qualify the generic. I find more strange that if you try with `let slist: seq[string] = map[int, string](nlist, (proc (v: auto): auto = $v))` the error message is `Error: A nested proc can have generic parameters only when it is used as an operand to another routine and the types of the generic paramers can be inferred from the expected signature.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that [map is just a normal proc](https://nim-lang.org/docs/sequtils.html#map%2CopenArray%5BT%5D%2Cproc%28T%29) which accepts two parameters, and you happen to be able to use it as `first.map(second)`, due to the [method call syntax](https://nim-lang.org/docs/manual.html#procedures-method-call-syntax), but there are [some limitations](https://nim-lang.org/docs/manual.html#templates-limitations-of-the-method-call-syntax). In fact, if you write that code as a normal proc call:

```
import sequtils

let nlist = @[1, 2]
let slist: seq[string] = map[int, string](nlist, proc (v: auto): auto = $v)
```

Then the compiler is not *confused* any more by the syntax and throws you a proper reason:

> Error: A nested proc can have generic parameters only when it is used as an operand to another routine and the types of the generic paramers can be inferred from the expected signature.